# My graceful stop http.ListenAndServe fails

Tags: http, go

I'm a novice Go programmer.

I am writing a web application and I need the server to wait until the active requests are made before closing.

I wrote a handler that waits 5 seconds to answer. If I make a request and stop the server (before the 5 seconds) I get an "Unable to connect" error.

There is a way to stop listen new requests and wait to active requests get done?

Here my example

```golang
func main() {
    log.Infof("Starting (PID %d)...", os.Getpid())

    stop := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(stop, syscall.SIGTERM)
    signal.Notify(stop, syscall.SIGINT)

    listenAt := "127.0.0.1:8000"

    r := newRouter()
    h := &http.Server{Addr: listenAt, Handler: r}

    go func() {
        log.Info("Serving on http://", listenAt)

        if err := h.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()
    <-stop

    log.Info("Stoping ...")
    h.Shutdown(context.Background())
    log.Info("Bye :)")
}
```

Example Handler

```golang
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    log.Info("new request")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hola!")
}
```

Full example @ https://gist.github.com/nachopro/d80fa71ae49527e1ddcaf359b4ff488b

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this [blog entry](https://tylerchr.blog/golang-18-whats-coming/) and their example I found this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4674) and their [solution](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown). I saw that my problem isn't related to net/http module!

The real problem is the `log.Fatal(err)` inside `go func()`, changing it to `log.Info(err)` does not abort the shutdown process.

```
go func() {
    log.Info("Serving on http://", listenAt)

    if err := h.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        // log.Fatal(err)
        log.Info(err)
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to narrow down your max connection to 1 by:

```
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8000")

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Listen: %v", err)
}

defer l.Close()

l = netutil.LimitListener(l, 1)

log.Fatal(http.Serve(l, nil))
```

another way is using a global variable:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "sync/atomic"
    "fmt"
)

var toggle *int32

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    val := atomic.LoadInt32(toggle)
    if val != 0 {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Not Valid!")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
        return
    }

    atomic.StoreInt32(toggle, 1)
    // do stuff
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}

func init (){
    atomic.StoreInt32(toggle, int32(0))
}
```

**notice both ways works for single node servers and does not work in distributed systems, solution for that is using cache servers like redis etc.

Comment: Could you expand your explanation? I understand your advice but I can not apply it in my example. Thanks.

Comment: added snippet for second way